# Regex to Match Specific Format with Space in it

Tags: regex

I got a huge list that contains some numbers that I want to remove

```
9172226511@                                                 0
9172226512@                                                 0
9172226513@                                                 0
9172226514@                                                 0
```

As one can see there is a big space between the @ and the 0 so what would be the correct regex to match

numberstring@                                                 0

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `.. want to remove ..` -- ok, feel free.  you didn't need our permission, did you?

Comment: what do you want to remove exactly?  Both the left-hand and the right-hand numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Regex to match:

```
^\d+@\s+\d$
```

If you want to do it using replace, then replace all `\s+` with single space(" ")

Answer (score 0):

More specific Regex:

```
^\d+@\s+0$
```